# SQLite + Searchbar + uitableview

Tags: sqlite, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to use SQlite with uisearchbar and uitableview. There is any example for this.
I find many examples for Uisearchbar with uitableview and sqlite with uitableview but not see any example for Mixed up of three.

Please show me any link if there is possible.
OR sample code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's the same when we have data in table view and search it. We select data from database to show in table view after we search it.